# Head also gets modified when working with LinkedList

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I was trying to check for palindrome Linked List, but head also gets modified and reached to end. Can someone help me why this is happening and how to resolve it?

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(ListNode head) {
        if(head.next == null){
            return true;
        }
        ListNode curr = head;
        ListNode prev = null;
        ListNode temp;
        while(curr != null){
            temp = curr.next;
            curr.next = prev;
            prev = curr;
            curr = temp;
        }

        curr = head;
        while(curr != null){
            if(prev.val != curr.val){
                return false;
            }
            curr = curr.next;
            prev = prev.next;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I tried to create another reverse method and pass head as value but then also head is getting changed.

Comment: You're *modifying the list* (`curr.next = prev;`) in a method that is only meant to be testing something. I haven't looked at anything else, but that's definitely not a good thing to be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're facing is happening because the code you've written is actually modifying the original linked list when you reverse it. This means that after the reversal, the head of the linked list is now pointing to the end of the list, and you're effectively losing access to the rest of the elements.

To fix this, you should create a copy of the linked list before reversing it. You can do this by creating a new linked list and copying the values from the original list to the new one.

Solution:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(ListNode head) {
        // Create a copy of the linked list
        ListNode copy = new ListNode(head.val);
        ListNode copyCurr = copy;
        ListNode curr = head.next;

        while (curr != null) {
            copyCurr.next = new ListNode(curr.val);
            copyCurr = copyCurr.next;
            curr = curr.next;
        }

        // Reverse the copy
        ListNode prev = null;
        ListNode temp;
        curr = copy;
        while (curr != null) {
            temp = curr.next;
            curr.next = prev;
            prev = curr;
            curr = temp;
        }

        // Compare the original and reversed linked lists
        curr = head;
        while (curr != null) {
            if (prev.val != curr.val) {
                return false;
            }
            curr = curr.next;
            prev = prev.next;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

In this code, I've added a step to create a copy of the linked list (copy) before reversing it. The copy linked list is then used for the comparison, while the original head remains intact. This should resolve the issue you were facing.

Answer (score 0):

/* Java program to check if linked list is palindrome */

class LinkedList {
Node head; // head of list
Node slow_ptr, fast_ptr, second_half;

```
/* Linked list Node*/
class Node {
    char data;
    Node next;

    Node(char d)
    {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
}

/* Function to check if given linked list is
palindrome or not */
boolean isPalindrome(Node head)
{
    slow_ptr = head;
    fast_ptr = head;
    Node prev_of_slow_ptr = head;
    Node midnode = null; // To handle odd size list
    boolean res = true; // initialize result

    if (head != null && head.next != null) {
        /* Get the middle of the list. Move slow_ptr by
        1 and fast_ptr by 2, slow_ptr will have the
        middle node */
        while (fast_ptr != null
            && fast_ptr.next != null) {
            fast_ptr = fast_ptr.next.next;

            /*We need previous of the slow_ptr for
            linked lists with odd elements */
            prev_of_slow_ptr = slow_ptr;
            slow_ptr = slow_ptr.next;
        }

        /* fast_ptr would become NULL when there are
        even elements in the list and not NULL for
        odd elements. We need to skip the middle node
        for odd case and store it somewhere so that
        we can restore the original list */
        if (fast_ptr != null) {
            midnode = slow_ptr;
            slow_ptr = slow_ptr.next;
        }

        // Now reverse the second half and compare it
        // with first half
        second_half = slow_ptr;
        prev_of_slow_ptr.next
            = null; // NULL terminate first half
        reverse(); // Reverse the second half
        res = compareLists(head,
                        second_half); // compare

        /* Construct the original list back */
        reverse(); // Reverse the second half again

        if (midnode != null) {
            // If there was a mid node (odd size case)
            // which was not part of either first half
            // or second half.
            prev_of_slow_ptr.next = midnode;
            midnode.next = second_half;
        }
        else
            prev_of_slow_ptr.next = second_half;
    }
    return res;
}

/* Function to reverse the linked list Note that this
function may change the head */
void reverse()
{
    Node prev = null;
    Node current = second_half;
    Node next;
    while (current != null) {
        next = current.next;
        current.next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    second_half = prev;
}

/* Function to check if two input lists have same data*/
boolean compareLists(Node head1, Node head2)
{
    Node temp1 = head1;
    Node temp2 = head2;

    while (temp1 != null && temp2 != null) {
        if (temp1.data == temp2.data) {
            temp1 = temp1.next;
            temp2 = temp2.next;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    /* Both are empty return 1*/
    if (temp1 == null && temp2 == null)
        return true;

    /* Will reach here when one is NULL
    and other is not */
    return false;
}

/* Push a node to linked list. Note that this function
changes the head */
public void push(char new_data)
{
    /* Allocate the Node &
    Put in the data */
    Node new_node = new Node(new_data);

    /* link the old list of the new one */
    new_node.next = head;

    /* Move the head to point to new Node */
    head = new_node;
}

// A utility function to print a given linked list
void printList(Node ptr)
{
    while (ptr != null) {
        System.out.print(ptr.data + "->");
        ptr = ptr.next;
    }
    System.out.println("NULL");
}

/* Driver program to test the above functions */
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    /* Start with the empty list */
    LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();

    char str[] = { 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a' };
    String string = new String(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        llist.push(str[i]);
    }
    if (llist.isPalindrome(llist.head) != false) {
        System.out.println("Is Palindrome");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Not Palindrome");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: While it's helpful to share working code that solves the goal of the original code, it's important to answer the actual question that was asked. In this case, why the original code didn't work and how the programmer can fix it for themselves. Supplying the questioner with a whole slew of new code can be more less helpful than answering in plain English what/where the problem is.